# Merge test reports from different test runs (Protractor, Karma)

Tags: testing, karma-runner, protractor

I'm looking for a tool which is able to join my reports which are generated from different test runs. Let's say I have a certain build which runs my E2E from Protractor on 20 VM's how can I join those reports and create one summary out of it automatically.

Comment: are you using multi-capabilities and has all configuration under 1 config file? Or you execute your suite multiple times against different configs?

Comment: Actuallay both. I'm using multi-capabilities and run my tests in different builds which will create always dedicated reports.

Comment: I am not sure, but this module might be helpful for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter. I use multi-capabiities spec with it and it generates html version of the report for me